# Can I use a ContentPage in the constructor for new NavigationPage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application looks like this (subject to change)

```
var settingsPage = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage())
{
   Title = "Settings",
   Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_settings_25.png"
};

namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
    {
```

The application works but I am wondering did I make a mistake by having this inherit from a ContentPage even though it works.

Would there be any reason for me to change this to inherit from a Navigation Page? Does a navigation page offer some different methods I might be able to take advantage of later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly standard way to do it.  There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I was just concerned because of the type mismatch.  Does a navigation page offer more methods or some different methods I might be able to take advantage of?